# Amend foreach loop to output <li> based on variable of IDs

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to modify the way a category list is drawn on the front end of a Magento website (simple idea). I have a list of categories that I want to seperate and use with jquery accordiation, so for EG. I want a header "2010 and older" under which sit categories with IDs 1 to 10. Then I want a heading "2011" under which live categories with IDs 11 to 20.

The default category code below just loops through the IDs and echos out the category list in a `<UL>` - but I want to customise the `<UL>`:

```
<?php $collection = $this->_getCollection(); ?>
<?php if (count($collection) > 0) : ?>



    <?php foreach ($collection as $_category ) : ?>            

                <li>
                    <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('gallery/category/view/', array('id' => $_category->getId())); ?>"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_category->getName()) ?></a>
                </li>

    <?php endforeach ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

I can't see the wood for the trees! - I figured to pull the IDs into an array and draw the new structure based on IF statements, but no luck in building the array.

Can anyone see a quick way that I can break the loop to say, if IDs are 1 to 10 then list in `<li class="2010">`, then move on for IDs 11 to 20 in `<li class="2011">`  for eg.?

Many Thanks

Comment: If you use `id` HTML attributes, I think you need nested lists otherwise you would have duplicate id's.

Comment: Hi,I can use class IDs - no problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to check for category id's you don't want to display and use `continue;` to get the next:

```
<?php foreach ($collection as $_category ): ?>
<?php if ($_category->getId() == 10) { continue; } ?>
    <li>
        <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('igallery/category/view/', array('id' => $_category->getId())); ?>"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_category->getName()) ?></a>
    </li>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should divide your problem. One part is the output, which can be represented with a function:

```
<?php

$htmlLi= function($class, $url, $name) {
?>
                <li class="<?php echo $class; ?>">
                    <a href="<?php echo $url; ?>"><?php echo $name; ?></a>
                </li>
<?php
}
```

Then you have the logic to decide about the classname based on some id:

```
$classById = function($id) {
    $class = $id < 11 ? '2010' : '2011';
    return $class;
}
```

And you finally want to put this together:

```
<?php $collection = $this->_getCollection(); ?>
<?php if (count($collection) > 0) : ?>

    <?php foreach ($collection as $_category) {
        $id    = $_category->getId());   
        $class = $classById($id);
        $url   = $this->getUrl('gallery/category/view/', array('id' => $id);
        $name  = $this->htmlEscape($_category->getName());
        $htmlLi($class, $url, $name);
    } ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

This also demonstrates, that your own function `_getCollection()` does not already returns the data in the format you need it. It's probably better it would return the fields you really need for the loop:

```
$class, $url and $name
```